# When is a complete fan a normal fan?

Tags: convex-polytopes, co.combinatorics

Is there a characterization for when a complete fan in $\mathbf{R}^n$ is the normal fan of a polytope? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The characterisation is as follows: There should exist a piecewise linear convex function of the fan, linear at each face of top dimension and having different gradients at all these top-dimensional faces.

Indeed if you have a convex polytope $P$ with vertices $v_i$ in $\mathbb R^n$ this defines you a collection of linear functions $v^*_i$  on $\mathbb R^{n*}$ and the function $\max_i (v^*_i)$ will be a convex function of the dual fan satisfying the  above properties.

Comment: These piecewise linear functions that you describe remind me of "virtual polytopes", of which is known, I believe, that not all of them correspond to convex polytopes. Could you say a bit more about this direction, how to get from the piecewise linear function to the convex polytope?