# Realizing spherical complexes as convex polytope

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, polytopes, abstract-polytopes

A spherical polytope is the intersection of some closed hemispheres which is non-empty and does not contain a pair of antipodal points. A spherical complex is a tiling of the whole (d−1)-dimensional sphere by spherical polytopes. Equivalently, it is the complex obtained by intersecting a complete polyhedral fan with the a (d−1)-dimensional sphere centered at the vertex of the fan.

We know that every combinatorial information of a spherical complex can be realized as a convex polytope in dimension 3 by considering the so-called canonical polytope. The proof from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz%27s_theorem) seems to depend on the circle packing theorem and the midsphere theorem.

So my question is:

> Is any spherical polytope of dimension $n$ isomorphic to a convex polytope as abstract polytope for $n > 3$?

According to [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65677/is-there-a-midsphere-theorem-for-4-polytopes) the midsphere theorem is still unknown for higher dimension, so I suspect there is a counterexample. Any idea or reference is appreciated.

EDIT:

(1) The definition of spherical polytope is edited several times (see the discussion on comment)

(2) I just saw [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope#Approaches_to_definition) where it is stated that "convex polytopes in p-space are equivalent to tilings of the (p−1)-sphere." which seems to give a positive answer of my question, but no reference is provided there.

Comment: please give a link to your definition of spherical polytope.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I don't have the reference for higher dimension, but my intention is to generalize the definition for dimension 3 defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_polyhedron) as tiling of sphere. I edited the OP for a more formal definition. It seems the same question is discussed in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359932/is-there-a-spherical-analogue-of-polar-duality-for-spherical-complexes).

Comment: your definition of a spherical polytope seems to be wrong, at least wrt. the stated result: as a counter example consider the great dodecahedron {5, 5/2}: it well is contained within a sphere, the origin of which is contained in its interior, but you cannot provide a convex sphere packing with 5 pentagons per vertex.

Comment: @Dr.RichardKlitzing You are right. I am new to the theory of abstract polytopes and when I write the term "polytope" I have some additional conditions in my mind (like two faces intersect on their common face). I edited the question so that the terminology is same as the other question cited in my previous comment.

Comment: I am doubtful that the answer is yes, but I have nothing to back this up for now. [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/64582/108884) seems very related, but I think the current answer is not very helpful for you. It might hint to some relevant terminology though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to phrase your question is "whether every complete fan is (combinatorially equivalent to) the face fan (or the [normal fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_fan)) of a convex polytopes". The answer is *No* in dimension $n\ge 4$ and I will provide an example derived from the following non-polytopal 4-diagram:

[image]

This picture is taken from Example 5.10 in Günter Ziegler's book "Lectures on Polytopes". The book explains why this diagram is not the Schlegel diagram of any 4-dimensional polytope. It is important to note that the "outer cell" of the diagram is a simplex.

Now, consider this diagram $D$ embedded into a 3-dimensional affine subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ that does not pass though the origin. Let $|D|$ be the simplex that forms the "outer cell" of $D$.
Let $x\in\Bbb R^4$ be a point for which the convex hull $\Delta:=\mathrm{conv}(|D|\cup\{x\})$ contains the origin in its interior. This convex-hull is a 4-simplex and $|D|$ is one of its facets. Take the face fan of the simplex $\Delta$ and subdivide the cone over the facet $|D|$ into the cones over the cells of $D$. This is a complete fan in which no cone contains antipodal points. You can intersect it with a sphere to obtain a spherical complex.

Suppose now that $P$ is a polytope combinatorially equivalent to this complex. Let $y\in P$ be the vertex that corresponds to the vertex $x$ of the complex.
Its four neighbors in $P$ span a simplex $\Delta'$ (that corresponds to $|D|$ in the fan above).
But deleting $y$ from $P$ (i.e. taking the convex hull of all vertices of $P$ except for $y$) leaves a polytope for which $\Delta'$ is a facet (here we use that $\Delta'$ resp. $|D|$ is a simplex) and whose Schlegel diagram based at $\Delta'$ is exactly $D$. This is a contradiction.